# Python: Filtering lists with lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

Write a Python lambda function which takes a list called my_list and returns a list which includes only even numbers in the same order.

My solution:

```
f = list(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0), my_list))
print(f)
```

I'm having issues because I'm doing a homework problem online and it runs various test cases on it and it says my_list isn't defined. Which I understand why that is, because it isn't... but it seems like the question is looking for a broad function which I don't know how to do in this case.

2 questions:

1. Does my solution look correct?
2. If so, how do I tailor this so that the homework will accept various inputs?

Comment: You can just assign to `my_list` a list of arbitrary integers as test data, e.g. `my_list = [3, 7, 4, 1, 2]`

Comment: From the first line of your post, maybe you are looking for something like this?
`f = lambda lst: [x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]` You can call it on any list of integers.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look correct since `f` is not a `lambda` function but a `list`.
OK, it uses `lambda` but it is not `lambda`.

You would probably need to write something like:

```
f = lambda my_list: list(filter(lambda x: (x % 2 == 0), my_list))
```

or similar.

For example:

```
f = lambda my_list: [x for x in my_list if x % 2 == 0]
```

should also satisfy the requirement.

---

Of course now `print(f)` will "print the function".

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing a homework problem online and it runs various test cases

Your function is actually correct. But, well, online coding assessment usually use a `stdin` as input. Python use `input()` method to retrieve string from `stdin`. So if you want your submission accept various input, you probably need to add this.

```
my_list = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
```

That will split string input by space character `' '` to be a list. Then, all content in list converted to integer by `map` function. Since the return value of map function is not a list, you need `list` method to convert `map` result into list. The new list will be saved to `my_list` variable.

But, again, it depends on your input specification. If your input specification are eg: `"1, 2, 4, 5"`. use `', '` as split parameter.